# what's the differences between action and services?

Tags: ros, action, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now,I have learnt action 's related tutorials including creation of client and server,Also learnt services including serviceClient and serviceServer,now I want to know their differences,It seems that I can implement same functions that I need with the two methods,please tell me when and where to use them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234132/what%27s-the-differences-between-action-and-services?/) by [WuJeff](https://answers.ros.org/users/26465/wujeff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-05-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The main difference is that action (using actionlib package) allows to preempt a running task contrary to service which will continue the task until the end. Action is useful when you have to observe real-time constraints.

---

Originally posted by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) with karma: 201 on 2016-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-05-11**:
You can also have a feedback every times with actions as Jbot well said

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The main difference is the possibility to have a feedback when using action. When you use service, you can only have a result at the end of the service.

For example, you make a service and an action "goToPoint" :

- The service will answer you at the end if you have reached the desired point
- The action will send you every X milliseconds how many meters remain to do to arrive to the desired point

---

Originally posted by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) with karma: 429 on 2016-05-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WuJeff](https://answers.ros.org/users/26465/wujeff/) on 2016-05-11**:
thanks very much

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2016-05-11**:
No, that is not the main difference, but rather a manifestation of the crucial distinction: service calls *block*, actionlibs are *non-blocking*.